# NullPointerException: null when selecting “Debug 'app'”

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I'm getting the following error each time I select "Debug 'app'", the app runs when selecting "Run 'app'". This issue is only when selecting debug.

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidSessionInfo.isEmbeddable(AndroidSessionInfo.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getOldSessionTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:307)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:279)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:201)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:58)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:396)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$5.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have looked through similar questions on here, but none have helped. The stack trace doesn't help me fix the problem as it seemingly runs fine when not debugging. I have no idea how to fix it so it works with debugging, like it does with "Run".

Other questions similar to this one I have looked at, and they do not help me fix the problem.

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: @yole 1.5.1 is the version.

Comment: Please try updating to 2.1 which is the latest stable version; most likely this will fix the problem.